# I cant seem to create a window that updates what im listening to on Spotify

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

Ive been trying to make a app that will grab what the user is listening to on Spotify and the next song that will play so they can skip songs

So far i just want to grab what they are listening to which i can do, but i cant seem to be able to show it up in a window with tkinter

Anyone got links that will help me, or can just help?

Thanks so much in advance

````
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time 

SPOTIFY_GET_CURRENT_TRACK_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'BQB8Lx8s3NidrRVZB0CTG04EGYn-tLeD5gvTa-uk2sjuADzy3vJp5LvUrdcSRCGtaCD7GKBJXBmSFIprZQ_U5_YcvemHZ_ROlfVjwWbM2RH7wZ80lR-YX3C4oG12CEqURcet_djqf3d-ggwv-M-fms'



def get_current_track(ACCESS_TOKEN):
    response = requests.get(
        SPOTIFY_GET_CURRENT_TRACK_URL,
        headers={
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}"
        }
    )
    json_resp = response.json()

    track_id = json_resp['item']['id']
    track_name = json_resp['item']['name']
    artists = [artist for artist in json_resp['item']['artists']]

    link = json_resp['item']['external_urls']['spotify']

    artist_names = ', '.join([artist['name'] for artist in artists])
    progress_time = json_resp['progress_ms']
    duration_time = json_resp['item']['duration_ms']
    current_song_time = json_resp['progress_ms'] / json_resp['item']['duration_ms'] * 100

    current_track_info = {
        "id": track_id,
        "track_name": track_name,
        "artists": artist_names,
        "link": link,
        "progress": progress_time,
        "duration": duration_time,
        "song_time": current_song_time
    }
    return current_track_info


def CreateWin():
    # creating tkinter window
    current_track_info = get_current_track(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Current Song')
    root.geometry('500x500')
    root.config(bg='#84BF04')
    
    Wrds = '''
    "Image here" , 
    "Track" {name} ,
    "Artists" {Art} 
    '''

    message = Wrds.format(name = current_track_info['track_name'], Art = current_track_info['artists'])

    label = StringVar()
    label.set(message)

    L_label = Label(root, textvariable=label)
    L_label.pack()

    Button(root, text = 'Refresh', command = get_current_track(ACCESS_TOKEN) ).pack(pady = 10)
  
def Main():
    current_track_info = get_current_track(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    current_track_id = None
    CreateWin()
    while True:
        if current_track_info['id'] != current_track_id:
            pprint(
                current_track_info,
                indent=4,
            )
            current_track_id = current_track_info['id']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
    
    
    ```
````

Comment: You should do a bit more troubleshooting. If you want a quick and useful answer, try to give more precision about where the problem is lying.

Comment: I thought it was clear, my apologies. I'm able to grab the information from what the user is listening to (I've tested it by printing the answer in the terminal), it just won't create the window to display the information